# Remove Linq to SQL Association on Multi-Client DB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, multi-tenant

I have a multi-client DB (multitennant) with several tables.
Two of these tables are `tblEmployees` and `tblTitles`.
Now I have a relationship from `tblEmployees.empTitle` to `tblTitles.ttlID`.

That far everything is working.
But now I have to make the application for multiple clients/tennants.
So I added the fields `tblEmployees.empClient` and `tblTitles.ttlClient` and included them into the association.

This works fine for reading and for setting the persons title as well.
But if I try to remove the title (set it to `NULL`), SQL to Linq tries to modify both `tblEmployees.empTitle` and `tblEmployees.empClient` with is not allowed because `tblEmployees.empClient` is part of the primary key.
And so I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException:
An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a AppTitle and a AppEmployee.
However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (AppEmployee.clientID, AppEmployee.titleID) cannot be set to null.
```

How can I tell SQL to Linq only to modify field `tblEmployees.empTitle`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem as everyone else did:
I let LinqToSQL think, clientID was not part of the primary key and removed it from the association.
However I did not modify the database, so the database still enforces to use a title of the same client/tennant.